# How to convert a grayscale matrix to an RGB matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, rgb, grayscale

```
rgbImage = grayImage / max(max(grayImage));
```

or

```
rgbImage = grayImage / 255;
```

Which of the above is right,and reason?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To convert a [grayscale image](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-types-in-the-toolbox.html#f14-13941) to an [RGB image](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-types-in-the-toolbox.html#f14-20224), there are two issues you have to address:

- [Grayscale images](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-types-in-the-toolbox.html#f14-13941) are 2-D, while [RGB images](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-types-in-the-toolbox.html#f14-20224) are 3-D, so you have to replicate the grayscale image data three times and concatenate the three copies along a third dimension.
- Image data can be stored in many different [data types](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html), so you have to convert them accordingly. When stored as a [`double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) data type, the image pixel values should be floating point numbers in the range of 0 to 1. When stored as a [`uint8`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html) data type, the image pixel values should be integers in the range of 0 to 255. You can check the data type of an image matrix using the function [`class`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/class.html).

Here are 3 typical conditions you might encounter:

- To convert a [`uint8`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html) or [`double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) grayscale image to an RGB image of *the same data type*, you can use the functions [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) or [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html):

  ```
  rgbImage = repmat(grayImage,[1 1 3]);
  rgbImage = cat(3,grayImage,grayImage,grayImage);
  ```
- To convert a [`uint8`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html) grayscale image to a [`double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) RGB image, you should convert to [`double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) first, then scale by 255:

  ```
  rgbImage = repmat(double(grayImage)./255,[1 1 3]);
  ```
- To convert a [`double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) grayscale image to a [`uint8`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html) RGB image, you should scale by 255 first, then convert to [`uint8`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html):

  ```
  rgbImage = repmat(uint8(255.*grayImage),[1 1 3]);
  ```

Comment: I just made a test,seems `double(grayImage)` is the same as `grayImage`?And are `./` and `.*` divide and product operators in MATLAB? Seems `./` is the same as `/` ?

Comment: @user198729: The operators `./` and `.*` denote *element-wise* division and multiplication, so that each element of the image matrix is divided by or multiplied by 255. You can check the class (i.e. data type) of a matrix by typing `class(grayImage)`. While `double(grayImage)` and `grayImage` might *appear* to be the same, they may each be a different class (such that they store their values in different ways).

Comment: I tried various operations,but `/` and `./` never give a different result...And because `double(grayImage)` is the same as `grayImage`,`double(grayImage)./255` is also the same as `grayImage./255`.So,can you give two examples demonstrating why `./` and `double` are necessary?

Comment: @user198729: First, the command `A/B` will give the same results as `A./B` if `B` is a single scalar value. Writing `./` just makes it explicitly clear to whoever is reading the code that element-wise division is occurring. Second, I think it was clear in my answer that the use of `double` is only necessary when you want to convert from *another data type* to `double`. If `grayImage` is already of type `double`, no conversion is necessary.

Comment: Oh,seems I misunderstood `double` with `float point` alike data type in c/c++,thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

By definition, an RGB image has 3 channels, which implies you need a three-dimensional matrix to represent the image. So, the right answer is:

```
rgbImage = repmat(255*grayImage/max(grayImage(:)),[1 1 3]);
```

Be careful when normalizing `grayImage`. If `grayImage` is `uint8` then you will lose some precision in the `255*grayImage/max(grayImage(:))` operation.

Also, normalizing `grayImage` depends on the data. In your question, you used two methods:

```
rgbImage = grayImage / max(max(grayImage));
```

which normalizes the grayscale image such that the maximum value in the image is `1` and

```
rgbImage = grayImage / 255;
```

which only makes sense if the values in `grayImage` lie in the `0-255` range.

So it really depends on what you want to do. But, if you want an RGB image you need to convert your single-channel matrix to a 3-channel matrix.

Comment: I thought that by definition the max value of `rgbImage` is `1`,which denotes `white`,but this seems not the case ?

Comment: Not really, it depends on your usage of the image.