# How to convert gray scale image which assigned threshhold value in some pixel of original RGB image to RGB?

Tags: image, matlab, rgb, grayscale

1. I have original RGB image.
2. then, I convert it to gray scale.
3. then, I assign new threhold value into some pixel.
4. then, I need to convert the gray scale image from step#3 to RGB image.

I am trying on the step#4. Could you help to advise?

Comment: so basically you want to threshold (i.e. place upper/lower bound on) the intensity of an RGB pixel?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619668/how-to-convert-a-grayscale-matrix-to-an-rgb-matrix-in-matlab

Answer (score 1):

Check out `rgb2hsv` and `hsv2rgb` in matlab. Then threshold on the value matrix. This makes more sense to me.

Another possibility is to convert to grey scale but keep the original colour image. Then create a mask by thresholding the grey scale image and use that mask to discard the pixels above/below your threshold on the colour matrix.